# Does the adverb phrase modify "I" or "you"?

Tags: adverbs

> "I love you as a friend"

I think it modifies Object, but I want to know if adverb phrase could modify Subject?

Comment: I as a friend? No, it's *love* as a friend. See? The love action/feeling is not romantic love, but the love in a friendship. I kiss my grandmother as mother or other family memeber, more than as a friend but not as a girlfriend.

Comment: "Love" is transitive here with "you" as object. The PP "a friend" is predicative complement, but it is complement of the preposition "as" rather than the verb "love". For this reason, "a friend" is  called a predicative oblique, and the _as_ phrase is called a 'marked predicative complement'.

Comment: It's ambiguous. The speaker might love ***having*** the addressee as a friend, or he might mean his feelings for the addressee are those of a friend (as opposed to a potential sexual partner, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I love you **as a friend.**

'As a friend' is an adverbial which can be replaced by a one word adverb.

For example:

I love you **unconditionally**.

In both cases it's the manner 'how' you love that is being supplied by the adverbial component.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb phrase modifies neither the subject nor the object, instead modifying the verb, *love*.

An adverb phrase is a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverb. An adverb will always modify an adjective, a verb, or another adverb, and never a noun or a pronoun (*I* or *you*); therefore, the only option in this sentence for the phrase's antecedent is *love*.

Logically, as well, this makes sense. *As a friend* is how I love you, not the state of me or you.